# if and else statements JAVA

Tags: java

I'm practicing if and else statements and i did a guess your password string, if you input the right password a congratulation message appears but if you enter the wrong one another message appears that says "Please try again" the issue that im having is that i dont know how to set another congratulation message if the user guess the right password on try again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String password = "Shippuden345";
    System.out.println("Enter or guess the password: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(password.equals(guess));

    if (password.equals(guess)) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was correct");
        return;
    }
    else;
    {
        System.out.println("Please try again: ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String again = scanner1.nextLine();
    }

}
```

}

i want to set another message in here, if the user guess the password correctly after trying again.

```
 else;
    {
        System.out.println("Please try again: ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String again = scanner1.nextLine();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: A simple approach is to copy your `if (password.equals(guess)) {` logic into the `else` block, created a nested `if-else` statement. If you want to allow more than 2 guesses, you should read about the concept of "looping."

Comment: That semicolon after your `else` doesn't belong there. It works because you have a `return` in your `if` so it stops the function there anyway, but the block below it is not part of the `else` right now.

Comment: (To be clear about why the above is proposed as a duplicate: An incorrect password and an invalid input value both require the same kind of handling -- with a loop -- to be able to reprompt indefinitely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the input and processing of the input value inside an infinite loop (e.g. `while(true){}`) which you can break on the correct input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "Shippuden345";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter or guess the password: ");
            String guess = scanner.nextLine();

            if (password.equals(guess)) {
                System.out.println("Your guess was correct");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please try again: ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter or guess the password: aSD
Please try again: 
Enter or guess the password: 12H
Please try again: 
Enter or guess the password: Shippuden345
Your guess was correct
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you used a do while loop:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String password = "Shippuden345";
    String guess;
    do{
    System.out.println("Enter or guess the password: ");
    guess = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(password.equals(guess));

    if (password.equals(guess)) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was correct");
        return;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again: ");
    }

    }while(!password.equals(guess));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code. However, I have added it to a static void:

I have also added an `int` to be shown if the first attempt was incorrect. Hope you like it.

````
class s{

public static void check(){

int attempts = 0;

    String password = "Shippuden345";
    System.out.println("Enter or guess the password: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(password.equals(guess));

while(attempts < 5){
    if (password.equals(guess) && attempts == 0) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was correct");
        return;
    }
else
    if (password.equals(guess) && attempts > 0) {
        System.out.println("Attempt number "+attempts+" was correct.");
        return;
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Please try again: ");
    attempts++;
guess = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
check();
}

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop that starts after the first guess of passwords if the guess is incorrect and continues the loop if passwords entered in the following trials are incorrect.

Then breaks the loop when the password matches and prints the congratulate message.

Comment: There are a few different types of loops OP could use. You can try a while loop, where while the password is incorrect, you output 'Please try again,' then once the condition is no longer true, you display 'Congratulations'.